# How to remove an ASPNET Runtime?

Tags: asp.net, windows-10, dotnet-framework

I have an ASPNET Core Runtime that needs removed, but the means I've discovered doesn't seem to be working right.  This is Version 2.1.17, which is old and needs gone.  It is on a Windows 10 domain-joined machine.

Searching around I found that there's a dotnet uninstallation tool, but it didn't list that Runtime as an option.  Further digging around seemed to indicate that if I removed the correct SDK I should be able to take the Runtime out with it.

The command used here was dotnet-core-uninstall remove --sdk 2.1.513

This took out the 2.1.513 SDK alright, but 2.1.17 still shows up in the list of Runtimes when I invoke dotnet --list-runtimes, but isn't listed as something that can be uninstalled anymore if I use dotnet-core-uninstall list instead (which just has a blank space where Runtimes might otherwise be).

Is there another way to yank this out?  Folder is owned by SYSTEM so I would have to mess with permissions, but would that cause other issues?  It doesn't appear to be used and the associated SDK is gone, so it doesn't serve any more use (and 2.1.25, a more recent replacement, is on the system).

[image: Specifically that highlighted one]

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 - Try this:
Go to Setting ==> Apps & Features ==> Search Then Select Your Verstion ==> Select Uninstall

See Link Below:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-windows